# How to match pixel data obtained by capture card with original pixel data

Tags: opencv, screen-capture

I have two PC. Two computers is connected by capture card. My purpose is to enable PC1 to obtain PC2's screen pixel data without a difference in pixel values using a capture board.

Actually, the two images("Original image data of screen of PC2" and "Image data obtained by OpenCV videocapture() using capture card") don't look much different to the naked eye, but the pixel values ​​of the two are different.

Resolution of monitor of PC2 is FHD(1920*1080). And Specification of my capture card is this

HDMI resolution          Maxinput can be 4K@30Hz

Support video format     8/10/12bit Deep color

Video output format      YUB,JPEG

Video output resolution  Max output can be 1080P@30Hz

If it is not simply a matter of specification of the device, how can i obtain perfectly identical pixel data?
else if it is a matter of specification of the device, what kind of capture card should i buy?

Comment: What is *"capture card"* exactly please? How do you plan to ensure synchronisation? If *"capture"* card only produces JPEG or YUB encoded data, the pixels will not be lossless. JPEG is lossy so you'll never get out what you put in. YUB is normally subsampled, so that will not be identical to the original PC's pixels either.

Comment: @MarkSetchell capture card is device that receives video signals in real time, encodes them, and stores them in a disk. So, which format should I use to achieve my purpose?

Comment: I meant what manufacturer and model is it exactly... preferably with URL to it.

Comment: HDMI might use chroma-subsampled sRGB... so don't expect perfect reproduction. **show** your data. **show** the differences. don't hand-wave. don't be abstract.